# How to avoid safari fullscreen video to show other objects in the player window

Tags: video, iframe, safari, fullscreen, vimeo

I have a portfolio on my website. Sometimes I want to showcase videos. If there is more than one video on the same page, safari is showing parts of the other videos inside the fullscreen video view.

Tjek my site here: http://www.legraslegras.com/portfolio/henrik-bulow-video/

I've checked in other browsers, and everything seems to work just fine. It's only in safari browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the design of your webpage as opposed to the Vimeo player. The fullscreen behavior is likely deriving from the CSS of your WP theme- http://www.legraslegras.com/wp-content/themes/kalium/assets. Have you tried contacting the support services of your theme?